# Обновление Переменной

Tags: python

Недавно начал изучать Python. Создал простейший код.“Орел и решка”. `coin_flip` (ставка, Орел/ решка). Программа работает, действительно отнимает ставку от суммы при проигрыше и прибавляет при выигрыше, но переменная `money` не обновляется. Т.е. При выигрыше 100 монет будет 1100, при повторном выигрыше тоже 1100 вместо 1200. Я понимаю, что не обновляется из-за отсутствующих элементов, пробовал изменить/добавить, но из-за нехватки знаний не смог.

```py
import random

money = 1000

def coin_flip(bet,method):
    if bet > money:
        print("Not enough money")
    # Орел

    elif method == "Heads":
        method = 0
        num = random.randint(0, 1)
        if num == 0:
            plus_mon = money + bet
            print("You win " + str(bet) + ". Now you balance is " + str(plus_mon))

        elif num == 1:
            minus_mon = money - bet
            print("You lose " + str(bet) + ". Now you balance is " + str(minus_mon))
            return 

  # Решка

    elif method == "Tails":
        method = 1
        num = random.randint(0, 1)
        if num == 0:
            minus_mon = money - bet
            print("You lose " + str(bet) + ". Now you balance is " + str(minus_mon))
        elif num == 1:
            plus_mon = money + bet
            print("You win " + str(bet) + ". Now you balance is " + str(plus_mon))
            return
```

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что вы не только Python начали изучать недавно, но и программирование вообще. 
Можно, конечно, за вас исправить программу, но считаю, что будет лучше, если это вы сделаете сами. Для этого даю информацию к размышлению:

Обращаю ваше внимание, что глобальная переменная money, которая в принципе и должна содержать ваше текущее богатство, НИГДЕ не меняет своего значения. Подумайте, как это исправить!

Comment: С программированием вы угадали.Насколько я понял, мне нужно изучить области видимости.Если есть какой-то материал на эту тему,можете посоветовать.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, никогда не делайте пустых `return`. Во-вторых, разберитесь с областью видимости переменных (money). В-третьих, переменную нужно изменять, если хотите, чтобы она, простите, изменялась.

По-быстрому ваш код можно исправить так:

```
import random

money = 1000


def coin_flip(bet,method, money=money):
    if bet > money:
        print("Not enough money")
    # Орел

    elif method == "Heads":
        method = 0
        num = random.randint(0, 1)
        if num == 0:
            money += bet
            print("You win " + str(bet) + ". Now you balance is " + str(money))

        elif num == 1:
            money -= bet
            print("You lose " + str(bet) + ". Now you balance is " + str(money))

  # Решка

    elif method == "Tails":
        method = 1
        num = random.randint(0, 1)
        if num == 0:
            money -= bet
            print("You lose " + str(bet) + ". Now you balance is " + str(money))

        elif num == 1:
            money += bet
            print("You win " + str(bet) + ". Now you balance is " + str(money))
    return money
```

а затем:

```
money = coin_flip(100, 'Heads')
```

Comment: Сразу извиняюсь за свою тупость!Но вывод остался тем же.Если я ставлю 150 и получаю в общем 1150,то следущая ставка начнется опять с 1000,а не с 1150.Возможно я вопрос неправильно сформулировал

Comment: А как вы вообще запускаете программу? каждый раз запускаете скрипт целиком?

Answer (score 0):

Самое главное - это то, что Вы не изменяете значение переменной `money`.

Но Ваш код в целом довольно неуклюж, поэтому я также постарался оптимизировать его, главным образом убрав ветвление.

***Пример:***

```py
import random


def coin_flip(bet: int, method: str) -> int:
    # Начальные проверки
    assert method in ('Heads', 'Tails')
    if bet > money:
        print('Not enough money')
        return money

    total = money                  # Создаём локальную переменную, используя значение глобальной
    total -= bet                   # Принимаем ставку; total = total - bet.

    rand = random.randint(0, 1)
    num = bool(rand)               # Приводим к логическому типу для удобства

    if method == 'Heads':
        num = not num              # Отрицаем переменную, вместо ветвлений.

    if num:
        total += bet * 2           # Награждаем в случае выигрыша

    # Сообщение с помощью формат-строк
    options = ('lose', 'win')
    print(f'You {options[num]} {bet}. Now you balance is {total}')

    return total


if __name__ == '__main__':  # Если не импортируем модуль
    money = 1000
    money = coin_flip(100, 'Heads')
    print(money)
```

Comment: Благодарю за проделанную вами работу!Я бы конечно мог соврать и сказать,что все понял,но это не так.Буду углубляться и изучать.

Comment: @George Если Вам что-то непонятно, то не стесняйтесь и спрашивайте. Буду рад ответить на все интересующие Вас вопросы. Если что, то могу создать отдельный чат.